# SVG shape transparency with solid color as a background

Tags: html, svg, shapes

I have an svg container which I used as a background, and inside it a circle is drawn

basically, this is what I've done:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" style="background-color:green">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

it creates something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y259kcjy/)

You can see the circle is transparent but it still has the green background from the svg tag,
how can I make the circle really transparent so it can appear as a hole (in this case it will be white since the page background is white), to make it clear this is what I want to display:
[image]

Is there any way that can make this happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a mask. Here you can see the red background cut through the rect.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="background-color:red">
    <mask id="mask">
        <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="black" />
    </mask>
    <rect mask="url(#mask)" fill="green" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The stroke of the circle is removed, how can you make that with the stroke still attached?

Comment: You'd need to draw a circle round the hole yourself. i.e add a circle after the last rect element.

Comment: thanks! it works! I added a few more mask layer, for the color of the circle (e.g. red with 50% transparent) and for the stroke as well

Answer (score 3):

I've added visible example of @Rober solution

```css
.svgClass {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  The text should be visible within the circle
</div>

<div class="svgClass">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" >
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="1" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
    </mask>
    <rect mask="url(#mask)" fill="green" width="100%" height="100%" fill-opacity="1"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```